# the react code where the inserted record from the django backend is not getting updated instantly after insertion unless the whole page is reloded

Tags: reactjs

> import React from 'react' import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
> import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'; import
> './expensetable.css'
>
> const ExpenseTable = () => {
> const [expenses, setExpenseData] = useState([]);
> const [url, setUrl] = useState('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/expensetracker/');
>
> ```
>   console.log(expenses);
>
>   useEffect(() => {
>     const fetchData = async () => {
>       try {
>         const response = await fetch(url);
>         const data = await response.json();
>         setExpenseData(data);
>       } catch (error) {
>         console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
>       }
>     };
>
>         fetchData();
>       }, [url]);
>   
>
>      return (
> <div>
> <div className="container mt-2">
>         { expenses.map((expense, index) =>(
>               <div className="row" key={index}>
>                  <hr />
>               <div className="container dataContainer">
>                     <div className="row">
>                           <p className='col-3 text-capitalize'>{index+1}</p>
>                           <p className='col-3 text-capitalize'>spender - {expense.spender}</p>
>                           <p className='col-3 text-capitalize'>spender amount - {expense.spender_amount}</p>
>                           <p className='col-3 text-capitalize'>spender date - {expense.spender_date}</p>
>                           <p className='col-3 text-capitalize'>category - {expense.category}</p>
>                           <p className='col-3 text-capitalize'>spent location - {expense.spent_location}</p>
>                           <p className='col-3 text-capitalize'>spender reason - {expense.spender_reason}</p>
>                           <p className='col-3 text-capitalize'>spender comment - {expense.spender_comment}</p>
>                           <p className='col-3 text-capitalize'>payment method - {expense.payment_method}</p>
>                           <p className='col-3 text-capitalize'>attachment - {expense.attachment ? expense.attachment
> ```
>
> : 'false'}
>
> ---
>
> )) }
>
>    ) }
>
> export default ExpenseTable;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your desired solution is Bit advanced. The API data you have fetched is executed only once and it is same till window reloaded or JSX is reattached.

Since you are using React I can suggest most popular library [React Query](https://tanstack.com/query/latest). You can use [Stale Time](https://tanstack.com/query/latest/docs/react/guides/initial-query-data#staletime-and-initialdataupdatedat) (Data expiration Time) or [Refetch Query](https://tanstack.com/query/latest/docs/react/reference/QueryClient#queryclientrefetchqueries) to obtain you requested functionality.

These are very advanced Topics. If you are standard programmer it takes 2 weeks to implement it.

All the best. Happy Coding!

**New Update:**

This can be used for normal use. Works fine. But not recommended for great projects

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function MyComponent() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [reload, setReload] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://backend.com/data')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => setData(data));
  }, [reload]);// Which means runs this function when reload value is  changed// Which updates your data

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    // Perform your save operation here as per your method
    setReload(!reload); // Reloads Data
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {/* Render your {data} here */}
      <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Save</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MyComponent;
```

Comment: is there any other solution for this if you know?????